# WPF Animate border background color

Tags: wpf, background, border, wpf-animation, coloranimation

I'm trying to animate the color of the brush for the background of a custom class that inherits from `Border`. I've tried the MSDN link here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.coloranimation.aspx

This is not exactly what I'm looking for, but can get me to a point with no errors but still, nothing is animating. The problem with the example is that they are defining the logic within a class that isn't the rectangle. I am trying to define from within the rectangle (actually the border).

Below is my code that I tried to extrapolate from MSDN for my situation.

```
public class PrettyButton : System.Windows.Controls.Border
{
    private System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush hoverColor = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush();
    private System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush origColor = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush();
    private System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard story = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard();

    public PrettyButton()
    {
        hoverColor.Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 50, 200, 0);
        origColor.Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);

        this.MouseEnter += PrettyButton_MouseEnter;
        this.MouseLeave += PrettyButton_MouseLeave;

        //Animate in logic
        System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation color = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation(hoverColor.Color, System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400));
        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(color, new System.Windows.PropertyPath(System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));

        story.Children.Add(color);            
    }
```

and below in the mouseEvent I have

```
void PrettyButton_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        story.Begin(this);            
    }
```

Unfortunately, I'm not getting any more errors so the trail has gone cold for me. I am also certain that I could probably find 10 solutions in XAML, but I would like for this class to be reusable in the future, and redefining this logic is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty`, try setting `"(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"`
Property Path.

```
System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(color, new System.Windows.PropertyPath("(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"));
```

Also set `Background` in `constructor` of PrettyButton as like this :

```
public PrettyButton()
{
    .....
    origColor.Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
    this.Background= new SolidColorBrush(origColor.Color);
    ..
    ....

}
```

**UPDATE :**

```
public class PrettyButton : System.Windows.Controls.Border
{
    private System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush hoverColor = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush();
    private System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush origColor = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush();


    public PrettyButton()
    {
        hoverColor.Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 50, 200, 0);
        origColor.Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);

        this.Background= new SolidColorBrush(origColor.Color);
        this.MouseEnter += PrettyButton_MouseEnter;
        this.MouseLeave += PrettyButton_MouseLeave;

    }

    private void PrettyButton_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard story = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard();
        System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation color = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation(origColor.Color, System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400));
        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(color, new System.Windows.PropertyPath("(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"));

        story.Children.Add(color);
        story.Begin(this);
    }

    private void PrettyButton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard story = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard();
        System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation color = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation(hoverColor.Color, System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400));
        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(color, new System.Windows.PropertyPath("(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"));

        story.Children.Add(color);
        story.Begin(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: This throws an `InvalidOperationException` on mouseEnter. `BorderBrush` does not point to a `DeependancyObject`in path `(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)`

Comment: this.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(origColor.Color); put this line in constructor...

Comment: Still no animation. Thanks for all the help, btw.

Comment: @JustinGrahn but it is absolutely working in my machine.. Can you please post where you are using this `PrettyButton` ??

Comment: I have tested in sample application. I just added a test `PrettyButton` on a blank white bg to see if something was changing that I wasn't noticing. Your solution does change the border color, but not the background color, which is what I need to change. I would like the border to be invisible.  Is it changing the background color for you?

Comment: Ohhh.. I thaught you need animation on BorderBrush.. It's fine just change `BorderBrush` to `Background`.. Check modified answer...

Comment: Ha! Thank you very much. I had actually tried this on my own, but hadn't added the `this.Background` in the constructor, so it was throwing an error.

Might I ask, where can I find out more about the `PropertyPath` value that you substituted for my op? It seems like magic (which means I need to learn more about it.)

Comment: Try googling it... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertypath(v=vs.110).aspx